# How to trigger a script when the systme is idle for certain time?

Tags: events

As the title mentions, is there any way to trigger a script or start/stop an app when the system has been idle for certain time? Similar to how screen is turned off from power settings etc.

Comment: define your understanding of *idle *

Comment: The heading asks a completely different question to the body.

Comment: @A.B.  sorry for the typo in the body. I meant to say "when the system is idle for certain time". "Idle" means what it sounds like.

Comment: @andy256 please read above comment.

Comment: @Bibhas what it sounds like is meaningless.